# Crear objetos en bloque asignando valores a campo many2many odoo8

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp

Estoy creando una funcionalidad para crear instancias de forma masiva desde un wizard, asignando valores a algunos campos many2many, pero a la hora probarlo recibo un error:

> ```
> "Expected singleton: modelo3(167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174,
> 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188,
> 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202,
> 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216,
> 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230,
> 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244,
> 245, 246)"
> ```

Creo que el error en la línea al intentar acceder al `modelo3,"""registros_many2many = i.mod2_modelo3_ids.ids"""`, porque lo he probado con otro tipo de campos del mismo modelo2 (formato fecha o texto) y funciona.

Os dejo el código por si podéis ayudarme.

```
class Modelo1Model(models.Model):
    _name = 'modelo1'

    mod1_modelo3_ids = fields.Many2many('modelo3')

class Modelo2Model(models.Model):
    _name = 'modelo2'

    mod2_modelo3_ids = fields.Many2many('modelo3')

class Modelo3Model(models.Model):act
    _name = 'modelo3'

#...   

class Modelo1Wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'modelo1.wizard'

    def _default_instancias(self):
        return self.env['modelo1'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids'))

    modelo1_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'modelo1',
        default=_default_instancias)

    @api.multi
    def create_modelo2(self):
        for i in self.modelo1_ids:
            registros_many2many = i.mod2_modelo3_ids.ids
            i.ensure_one()
            modelo2_obj = self.env['modelo2']
            modelo2_vals = {
                'mod2_modelo3_ids': registros_many2many
                }
            modelo2_create_id = modelo2_obj.create(modelo2_vals)
```